# Abort a pywinauto operation

Tags: python, pywinauto

I have a program that operates an external application using a thread. I want to be able call the abort() method of the thread to close the external application and immediately cease all pywinauto operations. Here is a simplified version of my attempt:

```
from pywinauto.application import Application
import threading
import time


class MyThread(threading.Thread):
  def run(self):
    self.app = Application().start('C:\\WINDOWS\\system32\\notepad.exe')
    window = self.app.window(title='Untitled - Notepad')
    window.wait('ready')
    while True:
      window.menu_select('Edit->Select All')

  def abort(self):
    self.app.kill()
    print("abort method complete")


thread = MyThread()
thread.start()
time.sleep(2)
thread.abort()
```

When run, it waits 2 seconds as expected, then prints "abort method complete", and then there is a long delay and a `pywinauto.timings.TimeoutError` and `pywinauto.findwindows.ElementNotFoundError` are raised. That is a sign that pywinauto is still running the `menu_select` operation even after `app.kill()`.

Is there any method to get pywinauto to immediately cease any active operations?

Comment: Could be because your infinite loop that's still running. Try changing it so it checks a flag or something and breaks out of the loop in if it's set.

Comment: I think that would work, but it would require me to check the flag before every pywinauto operation I do. I'm hoping there's a better method.

Comment: [Official Python docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html) tell that method `.abort()` exist for `Barrier` class only. So it seems you're not terminating the thread.

Comment: Right, so I would need some hypothetical `app.disconnect()` method that causes any active pywinauto operations to raise an error, which would get the thread out of the run method.

Answer (score 0):

```
while True:
 try:
    window.menu_select('Edit->Select All')
    break
 except:
    time.sleep(1)
    continue
```

try this code

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**

Answer (score 0):

In your code, a `MyThread` thread indefinitely continues to perform `Select All` menu action on `notepad.exe` even after the main thread killed `notepad.exe` by calling MyThread.abort().

So, like @martineau commented on the question, you have to introduce a flag that notifies the `MyThread` thread to abort the loop.

Notice `thread.join()` at the last; by calling join(), the main thread ensures and waits for the `MyThread` to finish.

```python
from pywinauto.application import Application
import threading
import time

class MyThread(threading.Thread):
  def __init__(self):
    super().__init__()
    self.is_aborted = False

  def run(self):
    """run on this thread"""
    self.app = Application().start('C:\\WINDOWS\\system32\\notepad.exe')
    window = self.app.window(title='Untitled - Notepad')
    window.wait('ready')
    while not self.is_aborted:
      window.menu_select('Edit->Select All')
      time.sleep(0.5)  # loop throttling
    self.app.kill()
    print("abort method complete")

  def abort(self):
    """can be called from other threads"""
    self.is_aborted = True  # boolean is thread-safe


thread = MyThread()
thread.start()
time.sleep(2)
thread.abort()
thread.join()  # wait until the thread finishes
```